# Only display title when there are results

Tags: php

Currently I have the following code to show related posts:

```
<?php

$cat_ids = array();
$postID = get_the_ID();
$categories = get_the_terms($postID, 'article-category'); //this will give all the terms

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    $cat_ids[] = $cat->term_id; //you may put some condition and consider only some specific terms as per your requirement
}

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'article', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query' => array(array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'article-category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $cat_ids //ids of specified terms
        )
      )
   );

$exclude = get_the_ID();
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<div class="posts-group">';
echo '<h2>More blog posts</h2>';
while( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
    if( $exclude != get_the_ID() ) {
        echo '
        <article class="post home-post">
            <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
                <div class="post-thumbnail-img">
                    ' . get_the_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, "small-thumbnail") . '
                </div>
                <h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>
            </a>
        </article>';
    }
endwhile;
echo '</div><br>';

?>
```

Now the `echo '<h2>More blog posts</h2>';` should only be displayed when we have related articles, now it's displayed every time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a conditional check before your loop to see if your query has any posts. And only display the title and the div if there is any posts to display.

```
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $your_query->have_posts() ) : // Add this line here to check if the query has posts.
    echo '<div class="posts-group">';
    echo '<h2>More blog posts</h2>';
    while( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
```

Also make sure to close the new IF statement after the end of your loop:

```
    endwhile;
    echo '</div><br>';
endif; // Add this line to close the IF-statement.
```

**Update:**

Exclude your current post in the Query to make this work. Otherwise the Query still contains the current post. Here is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ), //Add this line to exclude the current post.
    'post_type' => 'blog', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'blog-athlete',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat_ids 
        )
    )
);

$relatedquery = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $relatedquery->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<div class="posts-group">';
    echo '<h2>More blog posts:</h2>';
    while( $relatedquery->have_posts() ) : $relatedquery->the_post();
        //Removed the IF here
        echo '
            <article class="post home-post">
                <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail-img">
                        ' . get_the_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, "small-thumbnail") . '
                    </div>
                    <h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>
                </a>
        </article>';
        // Removed the closing of the IF here
    endwhile;
    echo '</div><br>';
endif;
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it still displays the title, did I do something wrong? http://pastebin.com/HYaknYSu

Comment: So I found out that it works for articles, but not for blog posts.. weird.

Comment: Updated the answer with new info.

Comment: Awesome, this works, cheers!